# Не генерируются множества tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Есть код с использованием библиотеки `tkinter` :

```
from tkinter import *
import pickle
import time
import random
from DiscreteMath.modules import initeq, log_oper, short_eq


class GUI:

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.s = self.save_to_file(self)
        self.A = set()
        self.B = set()
        self.C = set()
        self.U = set()
        Label(root, text="Set our sets by our own:", font="Arial 14", width=20, height=2, justify=LEFT).grid(column=0, row=2, columnspan=3)
        Label(root, text='A:').grid(column=0, row=3, sticky=E)
        Label(root, text='B:').grid(column=0, row=4, sticky=E)
        Label(root, text='C:').grid(column=0, row=5, sticky=E)
        Label(root, text='Set our sets by random:', font="Arial 14", width=30, height=2, justify=LEFT)\
        .grid(column=0, row=6, columnspan=3)
        Label(root, text='Amount of A\'s items:').grid(column=0, row=7, sticky=E)
        Label(root, text='Amount of B\'s items:').grid(column=0, row=8, sticky=E)
        Label(root, text='Amount of C\'s items:').grid(column=0, row=9, sticky=E)
        self.entA = Entry(root, width=30, bd=3, state=DISABLED)
        self.entA.grid(column=1, row=3)
        self.entB = Entry(root, width=30, bd=3, state=DISABLED)
        self.entB.grid(column=1, row=4)
        self.entC = Entry(root, width=30, bd=3, state=DISABLED)
        self.entC.grid(column=1, row=5)
        self.lenA = Entry(root, width=10, bd=3, state=DISABLED)
        self.lenA.grid(column=1, row=7, sticky=W)
        self.lenB = Entry(root, width=10, bd=3, state=DISABLED)
        self.lenB.grid(column=1, row=8, sticky=W)
        self.lenC = Entry(root, width=10, bd=3, state=DISABLED)
        self.lenC.grid(column=1, row=9, sticky=W)
        self.create_RadioButtons()
        but_student = Button(root, text='Student', font='Arial 12', command=self.student)
        but_student.grid(column=5, row=0, sticky=E, rowspan=2, columnspan=2)
        Label(root, text='Set the universal set up:', font="Arial 14", width=30, height=2, justify=LEFT)\
        .grid(column=2, row=6, columnspan=3)
        Label(root, text='From:').grid(column=2, row=7, sticky=E)
        Label(root, text='To:').grid(column=2, row=8, sticky=E)
        self.entU_vid = Entry(root, width=10, bd=3)
        self.entU_vid.grid(column=3, row=7, sticky=W)
        self.entU_do = Entry(root, width=10, bd=3)
        self.entU_do.grid(column=3, row=8, sticky=W)
        self.but_OK = Button(root, text='^Generate our sets^', font='Arial 12', command=self.generABC) # ЗДЕСЬ??
        self.but_OK.grid(column=1, row=9, columnspan=4)
        self.label_vyvid = Label(root, text='A = {}\n'
                                            'B = {}\n'
                                            'C = {}\n'
                                            'U = {}'.format(self.A, self.B, self.C, self.U),font="Arial 14", justify=LEFT)
        self.label_vyvid.grid(column=1, row=11, columnspan=100, sticky=W)


    def create_RadioButtons(self):
        self.var = IntVar()
        self.var.set(0)
        rad0 = Radiobutton(root, text="Вy our own:", variable=self.var, value=0, command=self.set_vruchnu)
        rad1 = Radiobutton(root, text="By random:", variable=self.var, value=1, command=self.set_vypadkovo)
        rad0.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W)
        rad1.grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=2, sticky=W)

    def set_vruchnu(self):
        self.entA['state']=NORMAL
        self.entB['state']=NORMAL
        self.entC['state']=NORMAL
        self.lenA['state']=DISABLED
        self.lenB['state']=DISABLED
        self.lenC['state']=DISABLED

    def set_vypadkovo(self):
        self.entA['state']=DISABLED
        self.entB['state']=DISABLED
        self.entC['state']=DISABLED
        self.lenA['state']=NORMAL
        self.lenB['state']=NORMAL
        self.lenC['state']=NORMAL

    def student(self):
        slave = Toplevel(root)
        slave.grab_set()
        slave.focus_set()
        slave.minsize(200, 80)
        slave.maxsize(200, 80)
        Label(slave, text='Севрук Артем\n'
                          'група ІВ-71\n'
                          'варіант {}'.format(self.variant(71, 19)),justify=LEFT, font="Arial 14").pack(fill='both')

    def variant(self, g, n):
        return (n+g % 60) % 30+1

    def from_string_to_set(self, x):
        x = x.replace(',', ' ')
        x = x.replace(';', ' ')
        x = x.replace(':', ' ')
        x = x.replace('.', ' ')
        x = list(x.split(' '))
        for i in range(x.count('')):
            x.remove('')
        x = {int(i) for i in x}
        return x

    def generABC(self):
        v = self.var.get()
        if v == 0:
            if self.entA.get()=='': self.A = set()
            else: self.A = self.from_string_to_set(self.entA.get())
            if self.entB.get()=='': self.B = set()
            else: self.B = self.from_string_to_set(self.entB.get())
            if self.entC.get()=='': self.C = set()
            else: self.C = self.from_string_to_set(self.entC.get())
        if v == 1:
            if self.lenA.get()=='': self.A = set()
            else: self.A = self.gener_vyp_set(int(self.lenA.get()))
            if self.lenB.get()=='': self.B = set()
            else: self.B = self.gener_vyp_set(int(self.lenB.get()))
            if self.lenC.get()=='': self.C = set()
            else: self.C = self.gener_vyp_set(int(self.lenC.get()))
        if self.entU_do.get()=='': do=0
        else: do = int(self.entU_do.get())+1
        if self.entU_vid.get()=='': vid=0
        else: vid = int(self.entU_vid.get())

    def gener_vyp_set(self, l):
        if self.entU_do.get()=='': do=0
        else: do = int(self.entU_do.get())
        if self.entU_vid.get()=='': vid=0
        else: vid = int(self.entU_vid.get())
        s = set()
        for i in range(l):
            s.add(random.randint(vid, do))
        while len(s) < l:
            s.add(random.randint(vid, do))
        return s


    def create_menu(self):
        m = Menu(root)
        root.config(menu=m)
        m.add_cascade(label="Window 2", command=SecondWindow)

    def save_to_file(self, x):
        f = open('Результат.txt', 'ab')
        pickle.dump(x, f)
        f.close()

class SecondWindow(GUI):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        GUI.__init__(self)
        self.icon = Toplevel(root)
        self.icon.title("Calculating")
        self.icon.grab_set()
        self.icon.focus_set()
        self.show()
        self.but = Button(self.icon, text='Зберегти в файл', font='Arial 12', command=self.s)
        self.but.grid(column=1, row=3)
        self.but.bind("<Button-1>", self.but_disable)

    def show(self):
        ur = LabelFrame(self.icon, text="Solution", font="Arial 14")
        ur.grid(column=0, row=5, columnspan=4)
        Label(ur, text='1) A - B = {f1}\n'
                       '2) B & A = {f2}\n'
                       '3) (A - B) | (B & A) = {f3}\n'
                       '4) ( (A - B) | (B & A) ) \ (C | B)  = {rez}\n'
                       'Відповідь: {rez}'
        .format(f1=log_oper.difference(self.A, self.B), f2=self.B & self.A, f3=(log_oper.difference(self.A, self.B))|(self.B&self.A), rez=initeq.initial_eq(self.A,self.B,self.C),font='Arial 14', justify=LEFT)).grid(column=0, row=5, sticky=W, columnspan=4)

    def but_disable(self, event):
        self.but['text'] = 'Збережено'
        self.but['state'] = DISABLED
        Label(self.icon, text='A = {}\n'
                          'B = {}\n'
                          'C = {}\n'.format(self.A, self.B, self.C),font="Arial 14", justify=LEFT).grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=W, columnspan=3)
        Label(self.icon, text='Заданий вираз:\n'
                              'D = ( (A \ B) | (B & A) ) \ (C | B) = {}\n'.format(initeq.initial_eq(self.A,self.B,self.C)),font='Arial 14 bold').grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=W, columnspan=2)
        Button(self.icon, text="Показати розв'язок", font="Arial 12",command=self.show).grid(column=0, row=3)

root = Tk()
root.title("Laboratory work 1")
root.geometry("680x400")
obj = GUI()
obj.create_menu()
root.mainloop()
```

Вроде все создается, но при нажатии на кнопку *^Generate our sets^*(т.е. объект кнопки - `but_OK`) ничего не происходит. В импортированных модулях все хорошо, там просто находятся функции обсчета множеств.
При нажимании на кнопку `but_OK` должен срабатывать метод `generABC` который в свою очередь заполняет пустые множества,определенные в ините.
В следующих строчках кода

```
self.label_vyvid = Label(root, text='A = {}\n'
                                            'B = {}\n'
                                            'C = {}\n'
                                            'U = {}'.format(self.A, self.B, self.C, self.U),font="Arial 14", justify=LEFT)
self.label_vyvid.grid(column=1, row=11, columnspan=100, sticky=W)
```

эти множества, по крайней , мере должны выводиться в главное окно как лэйбл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте "обновление текста" в код чтобы он отображался в виджете

```
....
def generABC(self):
    v = self.var.get()
    if v == 0:
        if self.entA.get() == '': 
            self.A = set()
        else: 
            self.A = self.from_string_to_set(self.entA.get())
        if self.entB.get() == '':
            self.B = set()
        else: 
            self.B = self.from_string_to_set(self.entB.get())
        if self.entC.get() == '': 
            self.C = set()
        else: 
            self.C = self.from_string_to_set(self.entC.get())
    if v == 1:
        if self.lenA.get() == '': 
            self.A = set()
        else:
            self.A = self.gener_vyp_set(int(self.lenA.get()))
        if self.lenB.get() == '':
            self.B = set()
        else:
            self.B = self.gener_vyp_set(int(self.lenB.get()))
        if self.lenC.get() == '':
            self.C = set()
        else:
            self.C = self.gener_vyp_set(int(self.lenC.get()))
    self.label_vyvid["text"] = "A = {}\nB = {}\nC = {}\nU = {}" \
        .format(self.A, self.B, self.C, self.U)

def gener_vyp_set(self, l):
    if self.entU_do.get() == '': 
        do = 0
    else: 
        do = int(self.entU_do.get())
    if self.entU_vid.get() == '':
        vid = 0
    else: 
        vid = int(self.entU_vid.get())
    s = []
    while len(s) < l:
        s.append(random.randint(vid, do))
        s.sort()
    else:
        print(len(s))
        return s
....
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо! 
так как вы немного разобрались, у меня еще один вопрос
При нажатии на окно Window 2, а потом на Сохранить в файл получаем окно с результатами .Как мне сначала получать окно с результатами?

Comment: А еще там не отображаются множества(

Comment: Если под множеством вы имеете `U` то у вас в коде нету какого то значение где `U` что то в себе хранит

Comment: @ArtemAleksandrovich  *"При нажатии на окно Window 2, а потом на Сохранить в файл получаем окно с результатами"* лучше создайте новый вопрос

Comment: Вопрос по этому вопросу) Попробуйте задать не 1,2,3, а другие цифры

Comment: так эти цифры - это количество элементов в множествах A,B,C

Comment: ну в А у вас 18 вместо 22-x элементов
в С 13 вместо 15-ти

Comment: Обновил ответ вроде теперь все корректно

Comment: боюсь,что нет, отправляет в зависание

Comment: так получается потому что метод `set()` не записывает повторяющиеся значение, и именно по в прошлом ответе была такая же проблема с кол-вом чисел